# django ckeditor running into unexpected errors

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, django-ckeditor

I am using django-ckeditor python package in my django app (django 1.11 + python 2.7). I have integrated it with s3 and it is hosted on Heroku. So far everything runs smooth.

Earlier I had an issue that non admin user could not upload images to server thus can not use any images as a part of their content. I fixed it by overriding ckeditor's browse and upload view. When i tested it it was working just fine. I pushed it to production.

Now none of my user can use ckeditors image upload or browse feature. when I try it, (as an admin or as regular user) it works. some users reported that app crashes, some said image wont show up despite uploading to server (also I can't see it in my s3 bucket.)

other images are working well with s3 for all users. but ckeditors images are working only for me, no matter which machine or which role I try as.

I also checked heroku apps, but they are not helpful at all.

Does anyone have idea any guesses why this could be happening.